Can i express $\arg(z_3)$ as a combination of $\arg(z_1)$ and $\arg(z_2)$?
if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are two complex numbers and $z_3=z_1+z_2$, can I express $\arg(z_3)$ in terms of $\arg(z_1)$ and $\arg(z_2)$. I want to do this so that I can see the individual contributions of $\arg(z_1)$ and $\arg(z_2)$ to $\arg(z_3)$. Is it even possible?

$\arg(u+v)$ is of course not a function of $(\arg(u),\arg(v))$. In other words: $\arg(r_1e^{is}+r_2e^{it})$ is not a function of $(s,t)$.

If $z_1=1$ and $z_2=ti$ for some $t\in(0,\infty)$, then $0$ is an argument of $z_1$, $\frac\pi2$ is an argument of $z_2$ and any number form the interval $\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$ can be an argumet of $z_3$. Does this answer your question?

This is not possible.
Take for an easy example $\arg(z_1)=0$ and $\arg(z_2)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Then $z_1$ is a positive real number, and $z_2$ is a purely imaginary number with positive imaginary part.
However $z_1+z_2$ can be anywhere in the first quadrant. In other words the value of $\arg(z_3)$ can be anything in the interval $\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)=(\arg(z_1), \arg(z_2))$.
So clearly the information $arg(z_1)$ and $arg(z_2)$ is insufficient to figure out $\arg(z_3)$.

We have, for $z_1 = a+bi$ and $z_2=c+di$, and $z_3 = z_1 +z_2 = (a+c) + (b+d) i$, $$\arg (z_1) = \arctan \left ( \dfrac {b}{a} \right ) \\ \arg (z_2) = \arctan \left ( \dfrac {d}{c} \right ) \\ \arg (z_3) = \arctan \left ( \dfrac {b+d}{a+c} \right )$$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$.
However, $\arg (z_1) + \arg (z_2) = \arctan \left ( \dfrac {b}{a} \right ) + \arctan \left ( \dfrac {d}{c} \right )  \neq \arg (z_3) = \arctan \left ( \dfrac {b+d}{a+c} \right )$.
To prove it, let $z_1 = 1+i$ and $z_2 = 1+i$.  Thus $z_3 = 2+2i$, and we have $\arg (z_1) + \arg (z_2) = \arctan \left ( \dfrac {1}{1} \right ) + \arctan \left ( \dfrac {1}{1} \right ) = \dfrac {\pi}{2}$, while $\arg (z_3) = \arctan \left ( \dfrac {2}{2} \right ) = \dfrac {\pi}{4}$.
Since $\dfrac {\pi}{2} \neq \dfrac {\pi}{4}, \arg (z_1) + \arg (z_2) \neq \arg (z_3) $.
